# Wingpanel crashes on search

Tags: wingpanel, crash, search

Installed `alacarte` menu editor, deleted "Install Elementary OS" icon, now when I try to search for an application, it crashes.  I also did an [update](/questions/tagged/update) & upgrade, so that may have caused it too perhaps.

Which logs should I paste here for help?  I found a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/slingshot/+bug/1600705)
but no fixes yet.  Except deleting `vim.desktop` from `~/.local/share/applications` which didn't exist for me.  However I did delete `~/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop`, which did nothing.  Oh and I had like 5 desktop files in that same dir for `chrome`, delete all them, did nothing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are using a live cd??

Comment: possibly, but I didn't have these problems before.  Some other issues with live cd (well, persistent live usb built using mkusb) I've resolved ie wrong sources.list entries and some other odds & ends - but otherwise it works great!

Comment: I don't think elementary OS is made to use it as a live usb with persistence... Yes, the option is there, but I don't think the devs have put many interest on making it work as a full installation.

Personally I'd recommend you to install elementary instead of using a live usb. It takes like 4Gb of space on your disk. I'm sure that with a 10Gb partition you could run it fine and install some apps that you need.

This is not the answer to your issue, but maybe it solves that problem as well!

Comment: I am actually facing the exact same situation. Deleted an entry with alacarte and now the wingpanel crashes when I try to search for an app. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`mv ~/.local/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications.temp`

I eventually removed the applications.temp folder.

[source](https://blog.b-nm.at/2017/05/08/elementary-os-wingpanel-main-menu-crashing-on-search/)